# Amazon Lex Integration into AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-lex

I have been working with Alexa Skills Kit for some time now with my code deployed in AWS Lambda written in Node Js. Now i want to integrate chatbots into it via the amazon Lex service. So that i am able to control my device using both Amazon Alexa and Amazon lex. My question was that if i use the same intent and slots name in Amazon Lex as i have did in my Alexa Skill would the AWS Lambda code just work out of the box? Or would i have to modify the AWS Lambda code to accommodate the AWS Lex?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to accommodate for the differences between Lex and Alexa. The most notable differences are the request and response formats.

### Notable differences to be aware of:

1. Major differences between the formats and passing of `sessionAttribtues` and `slots`.
2. Lex has 4 built-in `slotTypes` that Alexa does not use (yet?):  `AMAZON.EmailAddress,`, `AMAZON.Percentage`, `AMAZON.PhoneNumber`, `AMAZON.SpeedUnit`, and `AMAZON.WeightUnit`. ([Reference.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-builtins-slots.html))
3. Lex always passes the full user input through `inputTranscript`. Alexa does not.
4. Alexa provides `resolutions` for slot values but fills the actual slot value with the raw data extracted from the input.
5. Lex will automatically resolve a slot value if you have synonyms set for that `slotType`.

After working with both of them quite a lot, and often dealing with this, I much prefer Lex to Alexa. I have found Lex to be simpler and provides more developer freedom and control, even though you do have to conform to the restrictions of each of Lex's output channels.

### Compare Request / Response Formats:

**[Alexa JSON format](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html)**
**[Lex JSON format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html)**

### Example Alexa Request:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.[unique-value-here]",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.[unique-value-here]"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "key": "string value"
    },
    "user": {
      "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.[unique-value-here]",
      "accessToken": "Atza|AAAAAAAA...",
      "permissions": {
        "consentToken": "ZZZZZZZ..."
      }
    }
  },
  "context": {
    "System": {
      "device": {
        "deviceId": "string",
        "supportedInterfaces": {
          "AudioPlayer": {}
        }
      },
      "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.[unique-value-here]"
      },
      "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.[unique-value-here]",
        "accessToken": "Atza|AAAAAAAA...",
        "permissions": {
          "consentToken": "ZZZZZZZ..."
        }
      },
      "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
      "apiAccessToken": "AxThk..."
    },
    "AudioPlayer": {
      "playerActivity": "PLAYING",
      "token": "audioplayer-token",
      "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
    }
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

### Example Lex Request:

```
{
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "intent-name",
    "slots": {
      "slot name": "value",
      "slot name": "value"
    },
    "slotDetails": {
      "slot name": {
        "resolutions" : [
          { "value": "resolved value" },
          { "value": "resolved value" }
        ],
        "originalValue": "original text"
      },
      "slot name": {
        "resolutions" : [
          { "value": "resolved value" },
          { "value": "resolved value" }
        ],
        "originalValue": "original text"
      }
    },
    "confirmationStatus": "None, Confirmed, or Denied (intent confirmation, if configured)"
  },
  "bot": {
    "name": "bot name",
    "alias": "bot alias",
    "version": "bot version"
  },
  "userId": "User ID specified in the POST request to Amazon Lex.",
  "inputTranscript": "Text used to process the request",
  "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook or DialogCodeHook",
  "outputDialogMode": "Text or Voice, based on ContentType request header in runtime API request",
  "messageVersion": "1.0",
  "sessionAttributes": { 
     "key": "value",
     "key": "value"
  },
  "requestAttributes": { 
     "key": "value",
     "key": "value"
  }
}
```